# How to document a parameter is a function type in python

Tags: python, pydoc

```
def method(*, var_param, function_param):
    """Call 'function_param' with 'var_param'

    :param var_param: the value to pass to the function_param
    :type log: str
    :param function_param: the method to call with var_param
    :type function_param: ?????
    :return: Nothing
    :rtype: None
    """
    function_param(var_param)
```

I'm using pycharm 2017.1.1 to code and I was wondering what I need to put in the `:type function_param:` to indicate that a parameter is a 'function'?

== Edit ==

I tried using `function`, but pycharm complains:

[image: screen shot from pycharm]

Comment: I would have written `:type function_param: function` without thinking about it. `type(function_param) -> <type 'function'>`

Comment: I tried that but then pycharm highlighted the call of function_param saying it was not callable.

Comment: Weird. Did you definitely spell `function` correctly? Put what you tried in your question to help us debug it.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure I spelled it right. I've updated my original post with what I tried.

Comment: Does `:type function_param: callable` prevent the warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "callable" type.

```
def method(*, var_param, function_param):
    """Call 'function_param' with 'var_param'

    :param var_param: the value to pass to the function_param
    :type log: str
    :param function_param: the method to call with var_param
    :type function_param: callable[str]
    :return: Nothing
    :rtype: None
    """
    function_param(var_param)
```

Since your parameter is a `str`, you can set this in the function signature.

More info:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html

Comment: Thanks that is what I was looking for. It was hard to search for.